# logging into website using iframe

Tags: php, iframe

I want to display remote site password protected content inside iframe.  I want iframe to login automatically and displays the contents.
Kindly guide me how can i pass user/password in " iframe src "

```
<iframe src="www.mysite.com" style="height: 500px; width:500px" frameborder="0";></iframe>
```

Comment: Iframes = ugly.  This is what ajax is made for.

Comment: any one can pls help me . how to acheive this using iframes.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not!
Most of sites use POST mehod for login form then You can not login to this sites.
Of course if a site use Get method for login You can set login url parameter look like www.mysite.com?username=myuser&password=mypass

Comment: And DO NOT use a GET method like this.  You don't want to put a username and password in the page source.